# Beats Music, Why does this playlist's tracks fetch returns invalid results?

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm trying to fetch tracks for a specific playlist (pl128943612061942272) and it gives me strange results.

https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/playlists/pl128943612061942272/tracks?access_token=

The response has a total count of 15 but returns only 13 tracks.

Besides, if i try to get the 2nd track ( offset 1 and limit 1 ) by the following request, the response is empty.

https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/playlists/pl128943612061942272/tracks?access_token=&offset=1&limit=1

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because two of the tracks are no longer available. Songs sometimes become unavailable. This is often temporary.

Comment: Ok, that explains the count. But why is offset 1 and limit 1 returning empty results? Shouldn't it return the second track which is available in the playlist?